# Database schema for private messages with many different types of users

Tags: database, schema

I have almost 4 types of users in my system:

1- Students

2- Teachers

3- Admins

4- Parents

They must be able to send Private Message to each other.

and of course admins and teachers must be able to send PM to all Course students and all Term Students...

The problem is, I don't know how to set database tables with Foreign Key!?

Is it correct:

Table:Private_Messages (pmid,pmsubject,pmbody,pmdate)

Table:Teacher_Student_Private_Message (tspmid,pmid,tid,sid,sender)

Table:Admin_Student_Private_message (aspmid,pmid,aid,sid,sender)

Table:Admin_Teacher_Private_Message (like above)

Table:Admin_Parent_Private_Message (like above)

Table:Teacher_Parent_Private_Message (like above)

Table:Admin_Course_Private_Message (like above)

Table:Teacher_Course_Private_Message (like above)

Table:Admin_Term_Private_Message (like above)

Is there a more compressed solution?

Comment: You should have a single range of userids that spans all four groups. Then you only need a single table for all message types.

Comment: Thanks, but it's not possible :( I cannot change teachers and other table structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> You should have a single range of userids that spans all four groups.
>   Then you only need a single table for all message types. –  [Thilo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14955/thilo)

This gives tables and statements. A table contains the rows that make its statement true.

```
// assumes teacher(tid,...),student(sid,...),admin(aid,...),parent(pid,...)

user(uid) -- user [uid] is teacher or student or admin or parent
user_is_teacher(uid,tid) -- user [uid] is teacher [tid]
user_is_student(uid,sid) -- user [uid] is student [sid]
user_is_admin(uid,aid) -- user [uid] is admin [aid]
user_is_parent(uid,pid) -- user [uid] is parent [pid]

user_is_term_student(uid) -- user [uid] is term student
user_is_course student(uid) -- user [uid] is course student

message_was_sent(mid,sid,rid,date,...) -- message [mid] was sent by user [sid] to user [rid] at [date] ...
message_was_private(mid) -- message [mid] was private
```

(Observe that if you had just made statements about user ids you would have discovered they are straightforward not impossible.)

A superkey is columns with a unique value. A key is a superkey containing no superkey. Figure them out. Here are some:

```
user_is_teacher keys (uid),(tid)
message_was_sent key mid,(sid,rid,date)
```

A foreign key is columns whose value is a value of some key columns. Figure them out. Here are some:

```
user_is_teacher fk uid to user uid, fk tid to teacher tid
message_was_sent fk sid to user uid, rid to user uid
```

Suggest you write every design in this format.

Comment: Look! I have a separate table for each entity. a table for Teachers (tid is PRIMARY KEY), a table for Students (sid is PRIMARY KEY), and so on...

Comment: Unfortunately I did not understand :( Where should I apply this single range of userids? I have to add another column to all of base tables? and how can I set its AutoIncrement?

Comment: aha, now I got it. really nice solution. Thanks a lot ;)