# Inventory Database Design

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, database-design

I got 2 tables **User** and **Company**.
These two have a inventory.

***DataTables***

**Item**

```
ItemId | Name
================
   1   | Glass
   4   | Wood
```

**User**

```
UId | Name
============
 1  | Max
```

**Company**

```
 CId  | Name
==================
  1   | EvilCorp
```

**Inventory**

```
 RowId  |   UId  |   CId  |  ItemId  |  amount 
=================================================
   1    |   2    |   Null |    4     |   10 
   2    |   23   |   Null |    4     |   5 
   3    |   Null |   1    |    1     |   7
   4    |   Null |   1    |    4     |   70
```

Let say I have 500 users and 300 companys and every one has 20 inventory slots, I will have 16000 null values in my Inventory table (6000 UId nulls + 10000 CId nulls).

I want a SQL query that will say this information.

**Result**

```
Owner     | Item  | Amount
===========================
 MAX      | Wood  | 10
 EvilCorp | Glass | 7
 EvilCorp | Wood  | 40
```

My problem is that my **Inventory** table is bad due to all the nulls that will appears against CId when the record is for a User, and vice versa.

Do you know how to create a good table, without huge or/and complex SQL queries?

Comment: How will it create null values?  What would be complex?  Don't you need a separate table to hold the product being inventoried?

Comment: Yes, I allso have a Item Table.

Item
ItemId, Name
     1,      Glass
     4,      Toilet

My inventory table will look like this
RowId, UId, CId, ItemId, amount
     1,        2, Null,      4,          10
     2,      23, Null,      4,           5
     3,     Null, 2,         1,           7

If I have 500 users and 300 companys and every one has 2 inventoryslots, I will have 1600 null values in my Inventory table.

Comment: I can't read those records - can you them in your question in a table?

Comment: Its better? Need to get rep 10, so I can add a pic. Should been alot better :)

Comment: if it is null - then you have no record. no problem. ? not sure what i'm missing

Comment: One of Uid and Cid must be null, or else the system will be very messy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have Users, Companies and Owners. Users and Companies are Owners.

This is a common situation that can be put into tables various ways.

Every table holds the rows that make some statement true:

```
// "user [OId] has ..."
User(OId,...)
    fk OId references Owner -- a user is an owner

// "company [OId] has ..."
Company(OId,....)
    fk OId references Owner -- a company is an owner

// "Owner [OId] has ..."
Owner(OId,...)

// "[OId] owns [n] of item [itemId]"
Inventory(Oid,ItemId,amount)
    fk OId references Owner
    fk ItemId references Item
```

This comes from choosing tables that make plain statements about parts of your application. For variations read about subtables and supertables for subtypes and supertypes. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23913498/3404097) answer or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24137252/3404097) one.